# SharePoint Workflow completes prematurely when reaches the onWorkflowItemChanged event

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a workflow running on a forms list. The workflow has an OnWorkflowItemChanged activity sitting within a While activity. I know that the workflow enters the While loop and checks the while condition that has the value 'true', but it does not enter into the OnWorkflowItemChanged activity to execute its code. Once it enters the while activity it stop the workflow execution and sets the workflow status as 'Completed' in spite the fact that after the while activity there are several more activities.

What could cause the workflow completion when it reaches the onWorkflowItemChanged activity???

Answer (score 0):

If there are any unhandled exceptions in your activity, the workflow will move to complete status. Please debug your code and see if you can handle the exception.

Thanks!